# What is the purpose of surrounding a code block between glBegin and glEnd in brackets?

Tags: c, opengl

What is the purpose of surrounding the code in between the call to glBegin and glEnd in brackets? Does it have a programmatic or functional purpose or is it simply for aesthetics and style? Code below is in C.

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
glColor3fv(GREEN);
glVertex3fv(BLOCK_VERTICES[0]);
glVertex3fv(BLOCK_VERTICES[1]);
glVertex3fv(BLOCK_VERTICES[2]);
glVertex3fv(BLOCK_VERTICES[3]);
glEnd();
```

versus

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
{
    glColor3fv(GREEN);
    glVertex3fv(BLOCK_VERTICES[0]);
    glVertex3fv(BLOCK_VERTICES[1]);
    glVertex3fv(BLOCK_VERTICES[2]);
    glVertex3fv(BLOCK_VERTICES[3]);
}
glEnd();
```

Comment: Purely stylistic, I even do stuff like that. I know there are no variables at that artifical scope or anything like that, but it makes it easy to remember what a particular group of operations are relative to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason is style, because it somehow feels right to the programmer who wrote it.

It might have made some sense if he/she was also introducing local variables (i.e. looping to create vertices), but in C99 and later that's not necessary either.